# How can I add yearly control variables on daily Panel data?

Tags: regression, paneldata

I am working on a dataset where I have to regress daily stock return on daily ESG momentum scores, including some control variables. For market based measure of risk factors, I have added Fama-French factor loadings in the model which I have the daily data. But I have to add some other company specific controls (asset size, leverage etc.) in the model and those factors I have quarterly or yearly data. Can someone please describe what should be the process to include those controls. Should I keep those factors static over year and fill the daily columns with same number or do I have to do some interpolation?

Comment: Whatever you do it will be wrong. It is a missing data problem. You can use a lot of time reading about missing data solutions mostly likely figuring out that there is no clear-cut answer as to what is correct. I would save that time and simply 'fill the daily columns' as you say then you can always investigate other methods if you have time and check for robustness of results. You can justify the 'fill the daily columns' by arguing that the variables do not really change (a lot) during the time span they are assumed constant (which could be likely). This is just what I would do.

Comment: Thank you very much